# Ошибка Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object

Tags: python, telebot

[[image: Помогите мне пожалуйста!!][1]]

Описана функция вызова календаря. Использована готовая библиотека calendar-telegram из Git-Hub: https://github.com/unmonoqueteclea/calendar-telegram Не могу понять в чем заключается ошибка. Вылезла ошибка:
ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Судя по примеру https://github.com/unmonoqueteclea/calendar-telegram/blob/2b65fb102ab82165e4e8f5e11f4ade899d80f8c3/bot_example.py#L8 эта библиотека сделана для другой библиотеки ботов телеграмма -- https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot. Вы можете в своем проекте использовать ту библиотеку ботов, или найти другую библиотеку для календаря, или переписать calendar-telegram для текущей библиотеки ботов

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```py
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Choose the date", reply_markup=[markup])
```

Comment: Спасибо, но так не работает и не должно фактически, т.к. telegram-calendar написан на другой библиотеке для телеграм, и поэтому они вместе работать не хотят.

Comment: Можете выложить содержимое Вашей переменной `markup`? P.S. И не выкладывайте код скриншотом, пожалуйста :)