# помогите пожалуйста недавно начал изучать ботов и попалась 400 error

Tags: python, telegram-bot

A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object

мой код:

```
  import telebot

  from telebot import types

  bot = telebot.TeleBot('мой токен')

  @bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])

  def send_welcome(message):


       markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)

       item1=types.KeyboardButton('test')

       item2 = types.KeyboardButton('not test')

       markup.add(item1, item2)

       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello, 
       {0.first_name}!'.format(message.from_user), 
       reply_markup = True)


  bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1302448/373173)